# GIT: How is safe concurrent push implemented?

Tags: git, concurrency

Let's consider the example when git is used without daemon.

So we don't have git **"server"**, we only have central repo and two users with their git **"clients"**.

So, as I understand the work for adding new code to repo will be done by git programs of the users (by clients).

How is safe concurrent push provided?
Using central repo operating system file lock?
Or how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic protections against concurrent push are:

- avoiding concurrent push by pushing on dedicated branches
- protecting a branch ([GitHub protection](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) or [BitBucket protection](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) in order to allow only an integrator to push on it
- same idea (one integrator update a branch) by using forks ([GitHub fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) or [BitBucket fork](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/forking-a-repository-221449527.html)) in order to accept update only through pull requests.

But technically, concurrent pushes against the same branch of the same repo depends on how the git *backend* is managed.
That is what is being improved in [a proposed patch from March 2016 "refs backend"](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=145679361131371&w=4). It will:

- [making lock more generic](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=145679363031386&w=4) (meaning there is already a locking mechanism on the backend side, even if there is no lock visible by users)
- [resolve symbolic refs first](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=145679363931390&w=2) (with [symbolic ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) being -- [like HEAD](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References#The-HEAD) -- a regular file that stores a string that begins with `ref: refs/`. For example, your `.git/HEAD` is a regular file whose contents is `ref: refs/heads/master`.)

> **It is still possible to confuse git by concurrent updates, since the
>   splitting of symbolic refs does not happen under lock**.
>
> **So a symbolic ref could be replaced by a plain ref in the middle of this operation**, which would lead to reflog discontinuities and missed old-ref checks.

That patch would improve real concurrent update reliability.

Comment: It's worth noting that when using normal `git push` mechanisms and *not* re-pointing symbolic refs, git handles locking correctly (for some definition of "correct" anyway) such that one push completes before the other begins.  (This has been true since at least git 1.6 or so.  However, the post-receive scripts are not run with the lock held, which means two separate post-receives may both see the second update, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't have lock mechanism on server.

You can force some rules and policy with [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

In the hooks you can prevent developers to push code (**lock branches**), to limit and block a ***`force push`*** which will overwrite your previous history.

#### Summary

Git does not have a lock mechanism like in other SCM. Instead git use ***`hooks`*** which is basically script of any language which you OS can execute and there you can do anything you need.

---

#### Example:

Taken from [this article](https://dev.ghost.org/prevent-master-push/) here is a sample code:

#!/bin/bash

```
protected_branch='master'  
current_branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')

if [ $protected_branch = $current_branch ]  
then  
    read -p "You're about to push master, is that what you intended? [y|n] " -n 1 -r < /dev/tty
    echo
        if echo $REPLY | grep -E '^[Yy]$' > /dev/null
        then
            exit 0 # push will execute
        fi
        exit 1 # push will not execute
else  
    exit 0 # push will execute
fi
```